# argparse augment sub-command defaults via global options

Tags: python, arguments, default, command-line-arguments, argparse

I would like to be able to use the global options from an argparse.ArgumentParser object to override/augment the defaults values for a sub-command.

An example would be that displayed help reflects the global updates, i.e., for the following toy example:

```
import argparse
import os
import sys

# Global parser and options.
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

parser.add_argument("--user", 
                    dest="user", 
                    default=os.environ.get("USER"),
                    help="Override the setting of the $USER variable.")

# Sub-command parser and options.
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

command = subparsers.add_parser(
    "command",
    formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

command.add_argument("--config",
                     dest="config",
                     default="~%s/config" % os.environ.get("USER"),
                     help="The config file.")

options = parser.parse_args()
```

Ideally when when I run this in help mode I would get,

```
> python example.py --user thing command --help
usage: example.py command [-h] [--config CONFIG]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  --config CONFIG  The config file. (default: ~thing/config)
```

i.e., the config file path is user specific (thing). I realize that I could change the default config to be `"~%(user)s/config"` and then resolve this at run-time with the options namespace, however I would like the help to be more explicit.

I gather an alternative solution would be to try to parse the arguments once to obtain the global options, i.e.,

```
if "--help" in sys.argv:

    # Parse the command minus the help to obtain the global options. 
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    args.remove("--help")

    # Update the defaults with the global options.
    options = parser.parse_args(args) 
    command.set_defaults(config="~%s/config" % options.user)

    # Re-parse the options.
    parser.parse_args()
```

Though this seems somewhat hacky. Is there a better approach/solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After defining the global options, but before defining the subcommands, call `parse_known_args` to find out what the value of `--user` is. Then, finish defining the subparser commands, using the value of `--user` to define the default of `--config`, before
calling `parse_args` to parse all options on the command line.

This is a little different from your alternative, but it keeps all the command-line processing inside the `argparse` object.

(I trimmed down your code a little just to shorten it for this answer.)

```
import os
import argparse

# Global preparser and options.
preparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
preparser.add_argument("--user", dest="user", default=os.environ.get("USER"))

# ****** NEW *******
options, _ = preparser.parse_known_args() # Ignore what we haven't defined yet
user = options.user                       # Use this to define the default of --config

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[ preparser ], add_help=True,
                   formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

# Sub-command parser and options.
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

command = subparsers.add_parser("command")

# ****** MODIFIED *******
command.add_argument("--config", dest="config", default="~%s/config" % (user,))

options = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This approach is definitely much cleaner/simpler than my approach and more similar to an approach I was trying without argparse, i.e., parsing the arguments twice. I may look into the code to see how I can get parse_known_args() to return with options (as opposed to exiting) when the "--help" argument is provided rather than removing it per my example.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that. You can catch the `SystemExit` exception that `parse_known_args()` will throw when it calls `ArgumentParser.exit` (which is a relatively thin wrapper around `sys.exit`).

Comment: Hey, yeah I've tried that, however the issue with the try/except is that the options are undefined.

Comment: See my update; define a "preparser" that disables help; after it calls `parse_known_args`, you create the "real" parser using the preparser as a parent so you don't have to redefine all your options. This avoids the need to catch `SystemExit` as well.

Comment: Thanks that's awesome. I was thinking somewhat along the same lines of disabling and reenabling help, though your solution is significantly cleaner.

Comment: `parse_known_args` returns a two item tuple containing the populated namespace and the list of remaining argument strings.  you're putting the whole tuple into `options`.  Editing to replace with `options, _ = parse_known_args(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that modifies the help line directly, at runtime.  It could also modify `os.environ` or some other global as well, but I'll keep it simple.  The key is assigning the action created by `add_argument('--config'...)` to a variable.  `help` is just an attribute of that variable.  You are free to modify that.

```
class FooAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        config.help = 'new user (%s)'% values
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--user',action=FooAction)
sub = parser.add_subparsers()
cmd = sub.add_parser('cmd')
config = cmd.add_argument('--config',help='initial help')
config.help = 'default help' # alt way of setting 'help'
# print config  # to see other attributes of the config action
args = parser.parse_args()
print args
```

Invoked with just `cmd -h` we get the `default help`

```
$ python stack12167228.py cmd -h
usage: stack12167228.py cmd [-h] [--config CONFIG]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  --config CONFIG  default help
```

Invoked with `--user xxx cmd -h`, the help is customized

```
$ python stack12167228.py --user xxx cmd -h
usage: stack12167228.py cmd [-h] [--config CONFIG]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  --config CONFIG  new user (xxx)
```